# Azure Data Catalog Backup

Tags: azure-data-catalog

Since ADC is provided by MS as SaaS to customers, is MS taking backups of the dataset and business glossary? If yes, how often and how can a customer get access to the backups for recovery purposes?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. –

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, there is no explicit backup/restore feature available for catalogs.

I would suggest you to vote up an idea submitted by another Azure customer.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906052-data-catalog/suggestions/33125845-azure-data-catalog-backup-feature

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

---

The closest way to achieve this with current functionality is to use the Azure Data Catalog REST API  to extract all assets and persist them locally (and re import them manually later).

There is a sample application available that demonstrates this technique: [Data Catalog Import/Export sample tool](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/data-catalog-dotnet-import-export).

Comment: If it is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.